# WCF RIA Services getting the ID of inserted row

Tags: sql, wcf, key, wcf-ria-services, identity

I am using WCF RIA Services. I am not using entities and direct sql's. 
In my case stored procedures and complex types do all work. So I've faced with such a problem:
when i use store procedure to insert a row,there is no way to automatically update its ID from the database. In case of using entity and direct sql everything goes well.
Here is my stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    insert into Product
    (       
       [Name]
      ,[Note]  )
      values
      (      
    @Name,
    @Note   
      )      
      select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as ID

END
```

The only way to solve this -is to reload all the data againg after the insert.I think it is not good idea to load all the data, when only the one row must be updated.Second approach is to write some more code to get the new id manually from the SQL Server, but i believe there must be a better approach.

Comment: Perhaps this is my ignorance of WCF, but why doesn't this work? Why would you have to reload? Invocation of this proc should return a single row & column with the newly generated id (bonus points for using scope_identity instead of @@identify). newIdentity = (int) mySqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: While it's all good with your post,but WCF RIA Services offers some other opportunities :-). So I wonder if they are applicable in the case of stored procedures.

Comment: If you manually update the ID in your insert operation code (after executing the stored procedure) then the value should make its way back to the client.

Comment: This is actually the problem.After the insert operation I have still "0" as the ID if newly insterted row. When I use direct sql (e.g standart CRUD operations of the EF) this ID is automatically updated. I set the breackpoint at the set method, as is's really updated,while it's not even invoked when i use stored procedure.

Comment: Hi, Is here any progress with this? It seems, this is now exactly what I would need too. Thanks